# LVM , Causes server to not boot any more :(

Tags: linux, rhel, rhel6, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

So i have a linux 64 Bit RHEL 6.5 
with one hard disk running in raid "Mirror"

it is sliced into a few partitions, One of them being : 
/dev/sda8 750GB

I have done the following :

So i un-mount this partition and pvcreate , vgcreate  etc ... create my volumes the way i want I format both logical volumes in ext4

The problem is when i try to reboot the server the server does not boot back up it just hangs

Is it because i'm suppose to remount the /dev/sda8 back ?

Comment: Confused by 'one hard disk running in raid "Mirror"'... Mirroring by definition involves at least two disks...

Answer (score 1):

When you unmounted /dev/sda8, did you take it out of /etc/fstab?  If not, take that entry out of there, and make sure that you're not attempting to auto mount it with autofs.  Check /etc/auto.master, and the files listed in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using a Softlayer server since you tagged this post that way, so you'll want to use the KVM Console to see what exact error you are getting.

I'm guessing your server is still trying to mount /dev/sda8 and failing there. You can boot your server into the Rescue Image (in the control portal, go to the server -> actions -> Rescue) which will let you edit the /etc/fstab file.

I hope that helps.